# GGPLOT2: Error: unexpected symbol in: " geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Water_Pore-sd, ymax=Water_Pore+sd))

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot this:

```
     County Water_Pore   SD_Pore
1    Custer   43.64000  9.559752
2  Franklin   43.62636 10.723884
3     Keith   54.27875  4.993334
4      Knox        NaN        NA
5   Lincoln   32.17000 12.313772
6    Nemaha   56.96900  6.360114
7      Otoe   60.61143  6.131110
8    Seward   53.39813 10.578624
9   Sherman   31.32875  5.338045
10  Stanton   48.17917        NA


p <- ggplot(result, aes(x=County, y=Water_Pore)) + 
       geom_point(color="blue",size = 5 + 
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Water_Pore-sd, 
                         ymax=Water_Pore+sd))
print(p)
```

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Water_Pore-sd, ymax=Water_Pore+sd))

I am getting the points without the error bar. I want the error bars along with the points. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no closing bracket... try this:

```
p<- ggplot(result, aes(x=County, y=Water_Pore)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",size = 5) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Water_Pore-sd, ymax=Water_Pore+sd))
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `geom_errorbar` is referencing `sd` but it's called `SD_Pore` in the data. Probably meant to be:

```
 p <- ggplot(result, aes(x = County, y = Water_Pore)) +
        geom_point(color="blue", size = 5) + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Water_Pore - SD_Pore,
                          ymax = Water_Pore + SD_Pore))
```